# Polynomials bounded on integers

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

Let $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real valued polynomial, such that for all integers $0\leq i\leq n$ we have $b_{1}\leq p(i)\leq b_{2}$. Let $k=\max_{0\leq x\leq n}|p'(x)|.$ Then for all real $0\leq x\leq n$
$$b_{1}-\frac{k}{2}\leq p(x)\leq b_{2}+\frac{k}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \in [0, n]$ there is an integer $i \in [0, n]$ such that $|x - i| \le \frac 12$. The mean value theorem gives
$$
 p(x) = p(i) + (x-i) p'(t)
$$
for some $t$ between $i$ and $x$. It follows that
$$
 p(x) \le p(i) + \lvert x-i \rvert \lvert p'(t) \rvert
   \le b_2 + \frac 12 k
$$
The lower bound is obtained in the same way.